# Understanding Finding Duplicate Numbers And Returning The Lowest Index of The Second Occurence

Tags: javascript, arrays

Regarding the question that is to find the first duplicate number of numbers in an array for which the second occurrence,  has the minimal index.

If I understand so far, the variable firstDuplicate is a function object that uses arrow notation to abbreviate 'var firstDuplicate = function (a){}', etc. Here's where my questions begin.

1) Creating a new set object automatically populates using the array the function was passed? How does the set method know to take the array passed to the function and make a set of it?

2) Now I understand in the for loop that each item in the array is being traversed and the current index is e, but here is where I begin to lose conceptually what is going on.  Where in the following:

```
if (r.has(e))
```

where is the comparison happening exactly, that is the checking to see what the duplicative numbers are in this array, and the comparison that determines what the lowest index of the second occurrences of the duplicate are?

```
const test1 =  [0, 3, 4, 10, 2, 4, 2, 3]
  firstDuplicate = a => {
    r = new Set()
             for (e of a)
        if (r.has(e))
          return e
      else
        r.add(e)
return -1
}

console.log(firstDuplicate(test1));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Creating a new set object automatically populates using the array the function was passed? How does the set method know to take the array passed to the function and make a set of it?

Nothing is happening automatically here. The `Set` is populated in the `else` condition when you say `r.add(e)`

> Now I understand in the for loop that each item in the array is being traversed and the current index is e...

`e` is the current element and not the current index. You're using a [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) statement and not a [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) statement. Difference between the two using a simple snippet

```js
const a = [10, 5, 12];

console.log("for..in statement");
for (const i in a) {
  // Here i is the index
  console.log(i)
};

console.log("for..of statement");
for (const i of a) {
  // Here i is the element
  console.log(i)
};
```

> ...where is the comparison happening exactly, that is the checking to see what the duplicative numbers are in this array, and the comparison that determines what the lowest index of the second occurrences of the duplicate are?

The comparison happens at `r.has(e)`. So the code checks if `e` was already encountered (hence also added in the `Set`) and returns `e`. This works because if `e` was already encountered once, then if it's encountered again before any other duplicate, it automatically means `e` is at the minimal index.

Here is a commented version of your code, to make it more clear

```
const test1 = [2, 3, 6, 10, 2, 3, 7, 9, 1]

firstDuplicate = a => {
  // Create an empty Set
  r = new Set()

  // Iterate over every element of a
  for (e of a) {
    // Check if e was already encountered
    if (r.has(e)) {
      // If e was already encountered, this is the first time a duplicate
      // has been found. This is definitely a duplicate at the minimal index,
      // as a for loop iterates elements in order of their indices
      return e
    } else { // e is encountered the firt time
      // Populate the Set with e, to say that it has been encountered atleast
      // once
      r.add(e)
    }
  }
  // The if condition above never passed. That means array a has all
  // unique elements. Return -1, assuming the array a will never contain
  // -1 as one of it's elements.
  return -1
}

console.log(firstDuplicate(test1));
```

Comment: Thank you Maaz for taking the time.  I am examing your solution and may be back with a question about it.  Thanks.

Comment: So I just changed my original code I just replaced the array with different values with data I saw work.  [0, 3, 4, 10, 2, 4, 2, 3]  As you can see there are three duplicative numbers.  This returns 4.  As the index of 4's second occurrence, is smaller than 2's second occurrence, and 3's second occurrence. My question --For the first pass of each e, since r has not been initialized, it r is empty, so for the first pass, control will always flow  straight to the else clause, and populate r.  Is that right?  Shouldn't ' if (r.has(e))' always return true?

Comment: I don't understand where in the code it is comparing the indexes of the duplicative numbers to find who's second occurrence has the smallest index.

Comment: There is only one pass. So the flow goes into `else` only if the element is not found in the set. Otherwise, it goes into the `if` and returns that element. I've tried to explain it in the above commented snippet itself. Also, as explained above, there is no need to do any index comparison. The code just returns the first duplicate it finds (which automatically is the minimal index). Think of trying to solve this problem with multiple jumbled card decks. Would you bother to go through the other cards once you found a duplicate?